# Seletor 'body' não funciona no jquery do wordpress, só o '*'

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Estou fazendo um site usando o wordpress e o bootstrap.

Fiz inicialmente o site em php e converti para um tema do wordpress.

Não sei o que acontece com os seletores do jquery, eles funcionam no php puro, mas, não no wordpress.

Usei uma função para testar qual elemento estou clicando

```
$( "body" ).click(function( event ) {
  alert( "clicked: " + event.target.nodeName );
});
```

mas com o seletor `body`, não aparece nada, só funciona quando coloco o seletor '*'.

Alguém sabe o porquê deste comportamento?

Comment: Mesmo coisa, só funciona no php puro

Comment: Tenta usar o document ao invés do body: `$(document)`

Comment: Descobri o erro, o js estava carregando antes no head, agora não sei o porque o js só funcionava com o '*'

Answer (score 0):

Isso acontece porque o seletor universal `"*"` ([veja documentação](http://api.jquery.com/all-selector/)) habilita o clique em elementos mesmo ainda não carregados no DOM, porque ele seleciona justamente "qualquer elemento", sem importar se foi carregado ou não no DOM, porque ele não é específico, significa **qualquer um**.

Ao usar um seletor específico, como `$("body").click(...`, é necessário que o elemento exista no DOM, caso contrário o evento não surtirá efeito porque no momento da execução do script o elemento ainda não foi renderizado e adicionado ao DOM.

Neste primeiro exemplo irei criar um evento `click` apontando para a `div` antes dela ser carregada no DOM. Veja que nada acontece:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$( "div" ).click(function( event ) {
  console.log( "clicked: " + event.target.nodeName );
});
</script>
<div>Clique aqui. Nada irá acontecer!</div>
```

Neste segundo, irei posicionar o script após o elemento, e irá mostrar resultado:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Clique aqui.</div>
<script>
$( "div" ).click(function( event ) {
  console.log( "clicked: " + event.target.nodeName );
});
</script>
```

Neste terceiro exemplo, irei usar o seletor universal antes da `div` e mostrará que a `div` foi clicada:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$( "*" ).click(function( event ) {
  console.log( "clicked: " + event.target.nodeName );
});
</script>
<div>Clique aqui</div>
```

Outro exemplo que seleciona um elemento ainda não existente no DOM é usando o método `.on()`. Veja que o script está posicionado antes da `div`:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).on("click", "div", function( event ) {
  console.log( "clicked: " + event.target.nodeName );
});
</script>
<div>Clique aqui</div>
```